# How can I get a reference to the vue3datepicker object to programmatically close the date picker popup UI?

Tags: typescript, datepicker, vuejs3, vite

**Update**

- as yoduh pointed out I should not have `:` before the ref. I updated the code below and vue3datepicker is still undefined. Code updated based on yodubs point.

I followed these vue3datepicker [docs](https://vue3datepicker.com/slots/content/#action-buttons) to add my own **Action-Button** (Submit Button) and to get a reference to the vue3datepicker. In my 'Submit' button I also am calling the `close menu` function as described [here](https://vue3datepicker.com/methods-and-events/methods/#closemenu)

My issue is that my reference to the vue3datepicker object is always undefined and I'm not sure why.

I also followed this [code example](https://vue3datepicker.com/methods-and-events/methods/#closemenu) using the `DatePickerInstance` to get a reference to the vue3datepicker object.

My code is below and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VueDatePicker
      v-model="startDate"
      ref="datepicker"
      inline
      :month-change-on-scroll="false"
      :on-click-outside="onClickOutside"
    >
      <template #action-buttons>
        <el-button
          @click="selectDate"
          >Select
        </el-button>
      </template>
    </VueDatePicker>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import type { DatePickerInstance } from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'
import { ElButton } from 'element-plus'
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'

var startDate = ref(new Date())
export default {
  setup(props: Props) {
    //const datepicker = ref()
    const datepicker = ref<DatePickerInstance>(null)

    onMounted(() => {
      startDate.value = new Date(props.params.value)
    })

    const selectDate = () => {
      // !!!!!! datepicker.value is undefined here !!!!!!
      console.log('!datepicker: ' + datepicker.value)
      if (datepicker.value) {
        datepicker.value.closeMenu()
        const test = datepicker.value.selectDate()
        console.log('DatePicker.selectDate: ' + test)
      }
    }

    return {
      getValue: () => {
        return startDate.value
      },
      startDate,
      selectDate
    }
  },
  components: {
    VueDatePicker: VueDatePicker,
    ElButton: ElButton
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) should not be a binding

```html
<VueDatePicker :ref="datepicker">
```

`:ref="datepicker"` here expands to `v-bind:ref="datepicker"`, which is incorrect. It should just be:

```html
<VueDatePicker ref="datepicker">
```

and you need to return `datepicker` from the `setup()` function:

```js
return {
  getValue: () => {
      return startDate.value
  },
  startDate,
  selectDate,
  datepicker
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I made this change and my Datepicker is still undefined. Not really sure what I am missing here :/

Comment: Answer updated.  You also need to return anything from your setup function that you use in your template.  Sorry I missed it, I'm used to the much simpler `<script setup>` syntax for Vue 3 components.

Comment: The first console log in your `selectDate` function should then work.  Your second console.log that logs out the value of `const test = datepicker.value.selectDate()` will be undefined because you're running the function and then logging the undefined result.  If you want to see the function itself logged it should be `test = datepicker.value.selectDate` (no parenthesis)

Comment: that was it, thanks!